# search data based on date in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

i have a column(`scheduledStartDateTime`)  in database which is of type `datetime` and  i have to search previous row of data based on user entered `datetime` .

my query is like  this:

```
   order = self.trips_session.query(Order).filter(
                and_(
                    Order.driverSystemId == driver_system_id,
                    func.date(Order.scheduledStartDateTime) < func.date(start_date)
                )).order_by(
                DispatchOrder.scheduledStartDateTime.desc()).first()
```

[image]

my search date is  `2020-01-13 07:16:06` i,e order number `5673` so ideally i am looking for order number `5677` but i am getting is `5679`  . how can i compare dates based on hours minutes and seconds as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to convert a `datetime` however `func.date()` casts the `datetime` to `date`, therefore you are missing hour/minute/seconds. You just need to perform the comparison as normal, without casting your datetimes:

```
  order = self.trips_session.query(Order).filter(
                and_(
                    Order.driverSystemId == driver_system_id,
                    Order.scheduledStartDateTime < start_date
                )).order_by(
                DispatchOrder.scheduledStartDateTime.desc()).first()
```

Alternatively, if one of the datetime's provided is not in `datetime` format, you can use `func.datetime()` to cast it/them without losing the time information.